# Need an XPath that will check an attribute value of any child, grandchild, or great grandchild, etc

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

So given this XML...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <tree dah="false">
        <tree dah="false">
            <tree dah="false"/>
            <tree dah="false"/>
        </tree>
        <tree dah="false">
            <tree dah="true"/>
            <tree dah="false"/>
        </tree>
    </tree>
</root>
```

...I need an XPath that will evaluate to true since there is at least one tree/@dah='true'.

But that would evaluate to false if the XML looked like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <tree dah="false">
        <tree dah="false">
            <tree dah="false"/>
            <tree dah="false"/>
        </tree>
        <tree dah="false">
            <tree dah="false"/>
            <tree dah="false"/>
        </tree>
    </tree>
</root>
```

Also, the tree nodes may be any depth.  I have three levels in my example, but it could go much deeper.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for two XPath expressions that return a boolean value exactly as specified in your question.

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
boolean(/root//tree[@dah='true'])
```

or

```
boolean((/root//tree[@dah='true'])[1])
```

**Both expressions are equivalent**, but the second would be more efficient with dumb (non-optimizing) XPath engines.

**The result is** `true()` **if there exists a** `tree` **element in the XML document with a** `dah` **attribute with value** 'true' -- otherwise the result is `false()`.

Comment: Why the "boolean()" function?

Comment: Also, is the [1] to tell it to stop at the first occurrence?

Comment: @dacracot [Why the boolean() fn.] Because you want `true`/`false` returned and this is exactly what the `boolean()` function does: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-boolean

Comment: @dacracot [Also, is the [1] to tell it to stop at the first occurrence?] Yes, most XPath engines have at least this intelligence, not to evaluate the expression further.

Comment: /root//tree[@dah='true'] didn't work for me.
/root//tree[@dah=true()] did the trick

Comment: @Sidney, This means you either use a different source XML document, or are using a buggy XSLT processor.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Novatchev thanks you for the explanation. I'm using Ruby with Nokogiri, that may be why, I now know that this is not the correct behavior

Answer (score 1):

```
/root//tree[@dah='true']
```

Comment: I don't want the node, but your solution works as /root//tree/@dah='true'. Thank you.

Comment: //tree/@dah="true" or /root//tree/@dah="true" should get you just true or false.

Comment: @dacracot, MooGoo's answer *will* evaluate to true/false as you requested. If `/root//tree[@dah = 'true']` selects an empty nodeset, that evaluates to false in a boolean context. A non-empty nodeset evaluates to true in a boolean context.

Comment: /root//tree[@dah='true'] didn't work for me.
/root//tree[@dah=true()] did the trick